# How to implement live presentation - php?

Tags: php, jquery, live-streaming, presentation

I need to implement live presentation (something like presentation.io) where admin will control the slides and users should be on the same slide.

The requirement 
 
For www.url1.com 
 
1. There will be a admin who presents slides to users from www.url1.com. 
 
2. All users (there can be more than 100k+ at the same time) will access same URL to be on the same slide. 
3. When admin clicks next, all users should see next slide.

Same can be with www.url2.com

Please suggest technologies that I can use here or is there any third party tool available which supports such kind of process with n number of users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that WebSockets should do the job if you really want to do it in real-time. For client's code, there's a JS library Socket.io which helps using sockets. The server application could be developed with node.js.

I'm worried if one physical machine could handle 100k+ connections simultaneously. Maybe it would be enough for the client to ask server for updates simply via AJAX in 30 seconds interval?

Comment: This. You will need multiple servers to support that many users though.